# matlab and python abs and multiplication do not relate

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab

I have the following code in MATLAB and I want to translate it to python.

```
colB = [105.0767
  105.5614
  106.0449
  106.5258
  107.0050
  107.4866
  107.9851
  108.4947
  109.0013
  109.4960
  109.9605
  110.4045
  110.8459
  111.2929
  111.7416
  112.1844
  112.6098
  113.0130
  113.4014
  113.7805
  114.1556
  114.5232
  114.8870
  115.2418
  115.5799
  115.8978
  116.1978
  116.4827
  116.7571
  117.0246
  117.2874
  117.5453
  117.7982
  118.0483
  118.2948
  118.5366
  118.7699
  118.9948
  119.2122
  119.4192
  119.6140
  119.7980
  119.9737
  120.1432
  120.3069
  120.4619
  120.6076
  120.7430
  120.8684
  120.9849
  121.0936
  121.1953
  121.2909
  121.3822
  121.4687
  121.5482
  121.6184
  121.6793
  121.7327
  121.7801
  121.8223
  121.8599
  121.8927
  121.9187
  121.9363
  121.9468
  121.9504
  121.9476
  121.9385
  121.9211
  121.8975
  121.8681
  121.8334
  121.7908
  121.7433
  121.6928
  121.6422
  121.5917
  121.5411
  121.4906
  121.4401
  121.3895
  121.3390
  121.2884
  121.2379
  121.1873
  121.1368
  121.0862
  121.0357
  120.9851
  120.9346
  120.8840
  120.8335
  120.7829
  120.7324
  120.6818
  120.6313
  120.5807
  120.5302
  120.4796
  120.4291
  120.3785
  120.3280
  120.2774
  120.2269
  120.1764
  120.1258
  120.0753
  120.0247
  119.9742
  119.9236
  119.8731
  119.8225
  119.7720
  119.7214
  119.6709
  119.6203
  119.5698
  119.5192
  119.4687
  119.4181
  119.3676
  119.3170
  119.2665
  119.2159
  119.1654
  119.1148
  119.0643
  119.0138
  118.9632
  118.9127
  118.8621
  118.8116
  118.7610
  118.7105
  118.6599
  118.6094
  118.5588
  118.5083
  118.4577
  118.4072
  118.3566
  118.3061
  118.2555
  118.2050
  118.1544
  118.1039
  118.0533
  118.0028
  117.9522
  117.9017
  117.8512
  117.8006
  117.7501
  117.6995
  117.6490
  117.5984
  117.5479
  117.4973
  117.4468
  117.3962
  117.3457
  117.2951
  117.2446
  117.1940
  117.1435
  117.0929
  117.0424
  116.9918
  116.9413
  116.8907
  116.8402
  116.7896
  116.7391
  116.6885
  116.6380
  116.5875
  116.5369
  116.4864
  116.4358
  116.3853
  116.3347
  116.2842
  116.2336
  116.1831
  116.1325
  116.0820
  116.0314
  115.9809
  115.9303
  115.8798
  115.8292
  115.7787
  115.7281
  115.6776
  115.6270
  115.5765
  115.5259
  115.4754
  115.4249
  115.3743
  115.3238
  115.2732
  115.2227
  115.1721
  115.1216
  115.0710
  115.0205
  114.9699
  114.9194
  114.8688
  114.8183
  114.7677
  114.7172
  114.6666
  114.6092
  114.5455
  114.4754
  114.3984
  114.3143
  114.2233
  114.1255
  114.0206
  113.9087
  113.7891
  113.6609
  113.5247
  113.3807
  113.2295
  113.0714
  112.9060
  112.7329
  112.5516
  112.3614
  112.1599
  111.9472
  111.7239
  111.4946
  111.2590
  111.0142
  110.7592
  110.4902
  110.2065
  109.9060
  109.5896
  109.2629
  108.9231
  108.5721
  108.2080
  107.8307
  107.4411
  107.0378
  106.6259
  106.2053
  105.7731
  105.3310
  104.8843
  104.4318
  103.9728
  103.5068
  103.0305
  102.5438
  102.0497
  101.5431
  101.0189
  100.4735
   99.9116
   99.3448
   98.7798
   98.2161
   97.6443
   97.0568
   96.4461
   95.8170
   95.1775
   94.5390
   93.9049
   93.2778
   92.6581
   92.0322
   91.3820
   90.6952
   89.9731
   89.2305
   88.4928
   87.7724
   87.0845
   86.4269
   85.7820
   85.1406
   84.5003
   83.8508
   83.1875
   82.5056
   81.8090
   81.1094
   80.4259
   79.7570
   79.1035
   78.4643]
CD4_B0_col = zeros(length(B0_col),1);
    for i = 1:length(B0_col)
        if (i==1)
            CD4_B0_col(i) = abs(B0_col(i+1)-B0_col(i));
        elseif (i==2 || i==length(B0_col)-1)
            CD4_B0_col(i) = abs(B0_col(i+1)-2*B0_col(i)+B0_col(i-1));
       elseif (i>2 && i<length(B0_col)-1)
            CD4_B0_col(i) = abs(B0_col(i+2)-4*B0_col(i+1)+6*B0_col(i)-4*B0_col(i-1)+B0_col(i-2));
        else
            CD4_B0_col(i) = abs(B0_col(i-1)-B0_col(i));
        end
    end
```

My python code is the following (I think its good):

```
B0_col =  np.array(   [105.07667879044652, 105.5613777248652, 106.0449081509817, 106.52575610637302, 107.00499564553266, 107.48657205611589, 107.98511787367873, 108.49471095184933, 109.00129898214784, 109.49604219824592, 109.96049386457014, 110.40445303428619, 110.84592332323919, 111.29290125795949, 111.7415584650944, 112.18438066218506, 112.60982712605063, 113.01303084391708, 113.40138952129287, 113.7805363592266, 114.15560862629165, 114.52317260339136, 114.88701102708629, 115.24183634416714, 115.57988452380293, 115.89781586362314, 116.19784645709673, 116.4826675292113, 116.75709650065224, 117.02457857577812, 117.28744117483882, 117.54527523058013, 117.79822007489527, 118.04831649902856, 118.29478177778603, 118.53663147120618, 118.76985288681152, 118.99479947173607, 119.21222557380734, 119.41916861018635, 119.61404721770822, 119.79804992737525, 119.97372452112555, 120.14323005585807, 120.30689756912741, 120.46191225162659, 120.6075943070223, 120.74303031591633, 120.86840350845637, 120.98492862517824, 121.09364011563227, 121.1952892913203, 121.29085444658267, 121.38224884511483, 121.46871165942557, 121.54820239726212, 121.61836875124048, 121.67925196821798, 121.73267534516354, 121.78012383069321, 121.82234066107127, 121.85987220519327, 121.89268620284493, 121.91870073695361, 121.93629473570756, 121.9467770217112, 121.9504011345692, 121.9475647113194, 121.93851926831042, 121.92112418028479, 121.89749757959407, 121.86807064574144, 121.8333735344001, 121.79075613184469, 121.7433387027579, 121.69279080391163, 121.64224290506519, 121.5916950062189, 121.54114710737258, 121.4905992085263, 121.44005130967984, 121.38950341083357, 121.33895551198727, 121.288407613141, 121.23785971429452, 121.18731181544824, 121.13676391660195, 121.08621601775567, 121.03566811890923, 120.98512022006291, 120.93457232121662, 120.88402442237035, 120.83347652352396, 120.7829286246776, 120.73238072583132, 120.68183282698502, 120.6312849281387, 120.58073702929227, 120.53018913044599, 120.4796412315997, 120.42909333275342, 120.37854543390694, 120.32799753506069, 120.2774496362144, 120.2269017373681, 120.1763538385216, 120.12580593967536, 120.07525804082904, 120.02471014198275, 119.9741622431363, 119.92361434429003, 119.87306644544371, 119.82251854659745, 119.771970647751, 119.72142274890471, 119.6708748500584, 119.62032695121212, 119.56977905236577, 119.51923115351939, 119.46868325467308, 119.41813535582679, 119.3675874569805, 119.31703955813406, 119.26649165928778, 119.21594376044146, 119.1653958615952, 119.11484796274873, 119.06430006390246, 119.01375216505616, 118.96320426620987, 118.9126563673634, 118.86210846851714, 118.81156056967082, 118.76101267082454, 118.7104647719781, 118.6599168731318, 118.60936897428549, 118.55882107543921, 118.50827317659282, 118.4577252777465, 118.40717737890019, 118.35662948005391, 118.3060815812076, 118.25553368236118, 118.20498578351489, 118.15443788466858, 118.10388998582226, 118.05334208697583, 118.00279418812956, 117.95224628928327, 117.90169839043696, 117.85115049159053, 117.80060259274423, 117.75005469389791, 117.69950679505163, 117.64895889620517, 117.5984109973589, 117.54786309851261, 117.49731519966632, 117.44676730081991, 117.3962194019736, 117.34567150312728, 117.29512360428102, 117.24457570543467, 117.19402780658828, 117.14347990774198, 117.09293200889569, 117.04238411004938, 116.99183621120295, 116.94128831235665, 116.89074041351033, 116.84019251466407, 116.78964461581765, 116.73909671697135, 116.68854881812506, 116.63800091927874, 116.58745302043232, 116.53690512158605, 116.4863572227397, 116.43580932389344, 116.38526142504699, 116.3347135262007, 116.2841656273544, 116.23361772850811, 116.18306982966172, 116.13252193081537, 116.08197403196908, 116.03142613312278, 115.98087823427643, 115.93033033543004, 115.87978243658375, 115.82923453773745, 115.77868663889116, 115.72813874004474, 115.67759084119845, 115.62704294235215, 115.57649504350583, 115.52594714465944, 115.47539924581312, 115.4248513469668, 115.3743034481205, 115.32375554927411, 115.27320765042779, 115.22265975158147, 115.17211185273518, 115.12156395388878, 115.07101605504246, 115.02046815619617, 114.96992025734988, 114.91937235850351, 114.86882445965715, 114.81827656081084, 114.76772866196455, 114.71718076311825, 114.66663286427186, 114.60915104893375, 114.5455026712127, 114.47536495399498, 114.39841494847923, 114.31431176781162, 114.22331628896791, 114.12550643945637, 114.02058169962378, 113.90872568640812, 113.78906821444538, 113.66087444199421, 113.52466778528103, 113.3806552710153, 113.2295169994472, 113.07140263298271, 112.90599680882947, 112.73288345266148, 112.5516408007249, 112.3613739604525, 112.15988145322208, 111.94715844920572, 111.72388257040038, 111.49464301009483, 111.25898755608783, 111.01423580307016, 110.75921758256436, 110.49022914966581, 110.20651936993757, 109.90596136682568, 109.58956377211187, 109.2629356889294, 108.92306482052436, 108.57209518681937, 108.20796488509167, 107.83070246436095, 107.44109315723959, 107.03784977255091, 106.6258615100051, 106.20534619771772, 105.77311569479299, 105.331029695011, 104.8842761262788, 104.43182307486896, 103.97281246233412, 103.50683104333575, 103.03045745927737, 102.5437792453807, 102.04972006850294, 101.54314611628456, 101.01893184498753, 100.47347244364279, 99.9116317812473, 99.34483949553753, 98.77982659950578, 98.21609254710413, 97.64430905662022, 97.05676407499303, 96.44607397650215, 95.81704222274396, 95.17746835510187, 94.53901789829816, 93.90491062932094, 93.27783457010733, 92.6581462966101, 92.03220051597998, 91.3820221309281, 90.69522896072912, 89.97305496668487, 89.2305002855101, 88.49277821306397, 87.77240022465907, 87.0845103653809, 86.42689250984921, 85.7819658537025, 85.14055325470694, 84.50033094283842, 83.8508175678738, 83.18754110073226, 82.50555998739651, 81.8089697438873, 81.10937192242766, 80.42585531097062, 79.75697467299139, 79.103477516127, 78.46432781211549])

        # 1) 4th derivative of B0_col and B0_row using central difference method
        CD4_B0_col = np.zeros( (len(B0_col),1) )
        for i in range (0, len(B0_col)):
            if i == 0:
                CD4_B0_col[i] = abs ( B0_col [i+1] - B0_col [i] )
            elif i == 1 or i == len(B0_col)-2 :
                CD4_B0_col[i] = abs ( B0_col [i+1] - 2 * B0_col [i] + B0_col [i-1] )
            elif i > 1 and i < len(B0_col)-2 :
                CD4_B0_col[i] = abs ( B0_col [i+2] - 4 * B0_col [i+1] + 6 * B0_col [i] - 4 * B0_col [i-1] + B0_col [i-2] )
            else:
                CD4_B0_col[i] = abs ( B0_col [i-1] - B0_col [i] )
```

However the MATLAB CD4_B0_col is not exactly the same as the python result(np.array_equal(CD4_B0_col, Matlab_CD4_B0_col) returns False)  :

MATLAB result (seen in python):

```
Matlab_CD4_B0_col = np.array(    [0.48469893441867384, 0.0011685083021717446, 0.002588016916433844, 0.00287123316181237, 0.010687247900804664, 0.020554681927933416, 0.008130162108017203, 0.00521254215139777, 0.00960696924501292, 0.028245788739098998, 0.008204562679466676, 0.010007089314726159, 0.011824899882981299, 0.0036859091062382277, 0.004026440721958124, 0.006673710406843725, 0.01226471828250908, 0.0017645044598992854, 0.0004959324751752092, 0.008570987670111663, 0.0072164556572289484, 0.009070289769823603, 0.0024764776216130713, 0.004424328460416405, 0.005555795839455868, 0.0004751315186553029, 0.0021261956978690932, 0.0013722163268283794, 0.0011177841086436047, 0.002736487504094498, 0.00054839914739091, 0.0019014593510462419, 0.002823516438297702, 0.00020171476748487294, 0.0030282525160458817, 0.004366139611491349, 0.0004009006935064008, 0.0037169306665560953, 0.0013812196741014304, 0.0027698941670877275, 0.0013592509358062443, 0.00038872503918696566, 0.0018280193442592463, 0.0031458468615710444, 0.002135012973752737, 0.00023362306494334462, 0.0010966495459285852, 0.001031510388145307, 0.0001802909854831114, 0.0002831380484025203, 0.00022698283845556944, 0.0009349693550291249, 0.0026740911866625083, 0.0012796647615260781, 0.0003118151312833106, 0.0023935542413511257, 0.0017820501115863863, 0.000338348352840967, 0.0007417123517967639, 0.00019686736877133626, 0.0005786291099099117, 0.0020496568583041608, 0.00046084526091760836, 0.00292989441614111, 0.0010552829997294566, 0.00014409743306487144, 0.00014612068925146104, 0.002392141606065934, 0.004258757608994301, 0.0016869528483169915, 9.897617002252446e-05, 0.0031802693986122677, 0.0057703784080445075, 0.0014507079107062282, 0.0014609129873406346, 0.0031304697589291663, 5.258016244624741e-13, 2.2737367544323206e-13, 2.8421709430404007e-13, 6.110667527536862e-13, 6.252776074688882e-13, 2.8421709430404007e-13, 2.984279490192421e-13, 7.815970093361102e-13, 6.679101716144942e-13, 1.9895196601282805e-13, 1.2789769243681803e-13, 5.542233338928781e-13, 4.263256414560601e-13, 2.842170943040401e-14, 8.526512829121202e-14, 3.268496584496461e-13, 2.842170943040401e-14, 1.9895196601282805e-13, 1.4210854715202004e-13, 5.684341886080802e-14, 3.410605131648481e-13, 4.263256414560601e-13, 2.1316282072803006e-13, 2.8421709430404007e-13, 6.821210263296962e-13, 7.531752999057062e-13, 2.7000623958883807e-13, 1.7053025658242404e-13, 5.968558980384842e-13, 7.247535904753022e-13, 3.836930773104541e-13, 2.8421709430404007e-13, 5.968558980384842e-13, 5.826450433232822e-13, 2.5579538487363607e-13, 3.694822225952521e-13, 5.968558980384842e-13, 5.258016244624741e-13, 2.2737367544323206e-13, 1.7053025658242404e-13, 1.5631940186722204e-13, 5.684341886080802e-14, 2.2737367544323206e-13, 9.947598300641403e-14, 1.2789769243681803e-13, 4.689582056016661e-13, 5.684341886080801e-13, 2.7000623958883807e-13, 3.552713678800501e-13, 7.247535904753022e-13, 6.821210263296962e-13, 2.984279490192421e-13, 2.984279490192421e-13, 6.252776074688882e-13, 7.105427357601002e-13, 3.552713678800501e-13, 2.984279490192421e-13, 5.684341886080801e-13, 4.973799150320701e-13, 2.4158453015843406e-13, 2.1316282072803006e-13, 3.979039320256561e-13, 2.1316282072803006e-13, 1.8474111129762605e-13, 1.5631940186722204e-13, 2.842170943040401e-14, 2.7000623958883807e-13, 2.984279490192421e-13, 1.7053025658242404e-13, 1.4210854715202004e-13, 3.552713678800501e-13, 4.121147867408581e-13, 2.2737367544323206e-13, 9.947598300641403e-14, 2.984279490192421e-13, 4.547473508864641e-13, 2.5579538487363607e-13, 3.552713678800501e-13, 5.258016244624741e-13, 5.400124791776761e-13, 2.5579538487363607e-13, 1.5631940186722204e-13, 2.984279490192421e-13, 3.410605131648481e-13, 9.947598300641403e-14, 1.9895196601282805e-13, 2.1316282072803006e-13, 5.684341886080802e-14, 2.1316282072803006e-13, 1.1368683772161603e-13, 5.684341886080802e-14, 3.126388037344441e-13, 3.836930773104541e-13, 2.7000623958883807e-13, 2.8421709430404007e-13, 4.831690603168681e-13, 4.121147867408581e-13, 5.684341886080802e-14, 2.842170943040401e-14, 3.410605131648481e-13, 5.258016244624741e-13, 3.410605131648481e-13, 3.694822225952521e-13, 6.536993168992922e-13, 5.542233338928781e-13, 2.5579538487363607e-13, 1.9895196601282805e-13, 2.984279490192421e-13, 7.105427357601002e-14, 8.526512829121202e-14, 2.842170943040401e-14, 7.105427357601002e-14, 1.7053025658242404e-13, 2.5579538487363607e-13, 1.2789769243681803e-13, 9.947598300641403e-14, 3.979039320256561e-13, 4.263256414560601e-13, 7.105427357601002e-14, 7.105427357601002e-14, 1.9895196601282805e-13, 1.7053025658242404e-13, 1.4210854715202004e-14, 1.5631940186722204e-13, 2.5579538487363607e-13, 1.8474111129762605e-13, 7.105427357601002e-14, 2.1316282072803006e-13, 3.694822225952521e-13, 2.4158453015843406e-13, 2.842170943040401e-14, 4.263256414560601e-14, 1.9895196601282805e-13, 4.263256414560601e-14, 1.1368683772161603e-13, 1.4210854715202004e-14, 7.105427357601002e-14, 0.006933916491490777, 0.007701270600477983, 0.0010901312225257698, 1.716876738555584e-07, 1.7938052465638066e-05, 0.000601763829578772, 0.00018294946744390472, 0.0003784471614949325, 0.0004841365911971707, 0.0010538023020671972, 0.00013534362271627742, 0.0012582579677626882, 0.00031638951695356354, 0.00047307354061842943, 0.0005304378442048119, 0.00046502519833779843, 0.00010071153361934648, 5.68942782308568e-06, 0.00047312881338257284, 0.0013065860549517083, 0.0021966487942535196, 0.0006824518250141409, 0.0039115712917094925, 0.005041405490061379, 0.0022281931079248807, 0.0015102368317059245, 0.0025335764271261496, 0.002952610467659156, 0.0013757421170339512, 0.003135508335731174, 0.004600471351508872, 0.008621399887189796, 0.005156316676490746, 0.004205922645397209, 0.002090451742489563, 0.0007566835927264037, 0.0020724237890448194, 0.0061763908868357476, 0.004671371594568541, 0.003405969011410548, 0.00504783467582115, 0.0033282341270108873, 0.006219841634532486, 0.0001738352801368137, 0.00044483310885823357, 0.0030081132579056202, 0.003508893818178649, 0.002836131635447714, 0.008057479216745378, 8.268621442653057e-06, 0.0015207327689665817, 0.008468679966014747, 0.006565768739562827, 0.004698624744222002, 0.007231559040221214, 0.008827735664411307, 0.0016162286512297896, 0.0003284273406052307, 0.012187087316846146, 0.0029960797870103306, 0.0038659833388976494, 0.008445747734171505, 0.0005317550509857938, 0.002331445984424363, 0.014001868801969408, 0.004329804439549889, 0.005592916563529116, 0.013616142027117917, 0.013766175412911252, 0.010213159144399242, 0.012701820546581644, 0.0026325697729276953, 0.017360170465750002, 0.015364678981242719, 0.008403662127705047, 0.0068533722096759675, 0.008157580198997039, 0.0060093211422724835, 0.0004695249364345955, 0.009037070038033335, 0.007506036202272526, 0.007487235730053499, 0.02053402447788244, 0.002192744161789051, 0.0017835358990083705, 0.014347452852874198, 0.6391497040115155])
```

Does anyone know why this happens? or how to solve it?

I guess it is because abs is not the same in python and matlab or because the multiplications are not the same.

Comment: Can you define "exactly"?

Comment: Show a [mcve] in both matlab and python if you need help

Comment: Where do the results differ?

Comment: A minimal example would have just enough elements in the array to show the difference. There is no need to post so much data here. Please post both results, show us where and how they differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change one line:

```
CD4_B0_col = np.zeros((len(B0_col), 1))
# should be
CD4_B0_col = np.zeros(len(B0_col))
```

Example:

```
In[3]: CD4_B0_col = np.zeros((len(B0_col), 1))
  ...: for i in range(0, len(B0_col)):
  ...:     if i == 0:
  ...:         CD4_B0_col[i] = abs(B0_col[i + 1] - B0_col[i])
  ...:     elif i == 1 or i == len(B0_col) - 2:
  ...:         CD4_B0_col[i] = abs(B0_col[i + 1] - 2 * B0_col[i] + B0_col[i - 1])
  ...:     elif i > 1 and i < len(B0_col) - 2:
  ...:         CD4_B0_col[i] = abs(B0_col[i + 2] - 4 * B0_col[i + 1] + 6 * B0_col[i] - 4 * B0_col[i - 1] + B0_col[i - 2])
  ...:     else:
  ...:         CD4_B0_col[i] = abs(B0_col[i - 1] - B0_col[i])
  ...: 
In[4]: CD4_B0_col.shape
Out[4]: (300, 1)
In[5]: Matlab_CD4_B0_col.shape
Out[5]: (300,)
In[6]: np.array_equal(CD4_B0_col, Matlab_CD4_B0_col)
Out[6]: False
In[7]: CD4_B0_col = np.zeros(len(B0_col))  # <-- fixed
  ...: for i in range(0, len(B0_col)):
  ...:     if i == 0:
  ...:         CD4_B0_col[i] = abs(B0_col[i + 1] - B0_col[i])
  ...:     elif i == 1 or i == len(B0_col) - 2:
  ...:         CD4_B0_col[i] = abs(B0_col[i + 1] - 2 * B0_col[i] + B0_col[i - 1])
  ...:     elif i > 1 and i < len(B0_col) - 2:
  ...:         CD4_B0_col[i] = abs(B0_col[i + 2] - 4 * B0_col[i + 1] + 6 * B0_col[i] - 4 * B0_col[i - 1] + B0_col[i - 2])
  ...:     else:
  ...:         CD4_B0_col[i] = abs(B0_col[i - 1] - B0_col[i])
  ...: 
In[8]: CD4_B0_col.shape
Out[8]: (300,)
In[9]: Matlab_CD4_B0_col.shape
Out[9]: (300,)
In[10]: np.array_equal(CD4_B0_col, Matlab_CD4_B0_col)
Out[10]: True
```

Comment: When I run that code they are not equal. numpy array equal returns false. How is that possible, do you know any other possible solution?

Comment: @MiguiMag You must be doing something different, this is literally copy/pasted from my console showing that it works. Could you tell me which version of python you are running and copy paste your console after following these exact commands (like I did above) to something like bpaste?